# Cannot bind models in components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I define a component for my forms :

/resources/views/components/form.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($model, $form) !!}
{{ $slot }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and in the edit blade file I write some codes like this :

```
@component('components.form',[
        'model' => $user,
        'form' => [
            'route' => ['users.update', $user],
            'method' => 'put',
            'class' => 'col-sm-12'
            ]
        ])

{!! Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

@endcomponent
```

Unfortunately, the fields cannot fill with previous values.

But when I `{{ dump($model) }}` in `/resources/views/components/form.blade.php` the variable have a `Object` value.

What is the problem?

Comment: an `Object` value as in an stdClass object or an actual eloquent model object?

Comment: @apokryfos is an eloquent model object. the output is the same as `{{ dd($user) }}` in the controller